# A (Linux) server program acting as its own "client"

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I have a (Linux) program source code for which I need to write automated unit tests. One part of the program acts as a server, listening to a particular port (using posix sockets) and sending responses to it.

Is it possible to somehow have the same program act as its own "client"? In other words to send a request to that port, as it if were another computer, and read the response from that same port? In case this is not possible to do by interfacing with the port directly using sockets, if it's possible to do this with some kind of special file, that would be fine too.

(Yes, I know about mocking. That is not what I am asking. I'm literally asking the above question, nothing else. I literally would need to have the code I need to test to read the socket and write to it.)

I have tried googling for the answer quite extensively, but this is, once again, one of those questions for which google does not seem to want to give any relevant answers. (All the results are just about socket programming in general, or the same program acting as a server *or* a client, or a server for one thing and a client for another thing using different ports, not as "its own client".) man pages are also very long and obscure, and it's very hard to find this info from them.

Comment: I assume it would work, did you try it? Shouldn't be hard to test.

Comment: "(...) act as its own "client" " - this question is a bit obscure to me. Otherwise, yeah it's totally possible to send test data to the system that listens to the port using posix sockets. And absolutely yes, it can be done in your unit tests. Example (absolutely wild guess): `std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ socketConnection.sendData(testData); });` . What problem did you face trying to test your system?

Comment: This is not different than having two programs running on the same computer. However, all connections on localhost use loopback interface, so hardware is not accessed. So depending on your definition "as it if were another computer", the answer is either yes or no. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you applied! C and C++ are mutually exclusive in general.

Comment: I added both tags because the server code is written in C and the testing code is written in C++ (using googletest), in case that's relevant to the answer. (It probably isn't, but since the test program is effectively written in both languages, I thought both tags would apply.)

Comment: I understand the need for automated tests, but I don't understand why test code should be integrated within the same program. I'd recommend to keep production code and test code separated. In fact, test code does not even have to be written in the same programming language. I would first try a simple Bash script, and work from there. Just pipe test input into [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) and compare its output with a baseline file. For a more realistic time lapse, pipe the input through [pv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html) before passing it into netcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets don't care where connections come from, so of course it works.

Depending on the server architecture, it might have some implementation challenges, like if things aren't done asynchronously -- as in "your client-code makes the connect() to the socket and waits for it to succeed, but since it's waiting for the connect the server-part of the server can't accept it". Your code has to be able to run both things in parallel.

As long as your embedded client code doesn't make actual calls into the server code, you can just launch the client as a new thread, though. Pay attention to certain libc calls that return stuff in static buffers. Doesn't usually happen for the core socket part, but things like making nice timestamps for logs can call such functions.

That would fix such problems, and also allow you to implement the client in a blocking fashion if you prefer doing that.

Update: keep in mind that such a builtin "test" cannot find various things:

- it cannot find network issues, since it's not going through the network
- it cannot report a server crash, because the client will have crashed with it

Comment: I somehow assumed that the same program trying to read/write the same port from two different locations would just mess up itself, but it indeed appears to be so that two distinct socket instances can just communicate with each other through that one and same port just fine, and thus it's the perfect solution for this (with the caveats you mention that this doesn't actually test the network connection itself.)

Comment: @DjVortex: it actually does go through quite a bit of the network stack--it just uses the loopback adapter instead of a hardware adapter.